# App won't run without users setting minfree values to run it?

Tags: android

A user contacted me and said he needed to set "...minfree values" to get my Android app to run. What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Google is your **friend**, mate.

http://www.androidcentral.com/fine-tuning-minfree-settings-improving-androids-multi-tasking

http://www.chargeforums.com/forum/droid-charge-development/3144-good-minfree-values.html

http://www.vikitech.com/10319/boost-performance-android-phone-supercharger

http://tech-trip.com/android-memory-management/

It's all about **memory management and tweaking**. Your app. puts a heavy burden on his rig. So you might want to **optimize your code** and it's mem. usage.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check into it.

Comment: Cool... if it answers your question then accept the answer so others might benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks again. I did look online but the answers were confusing. Those articles talk about how to set free mem but I'm still unclear what it is doing and what it is for. And I've been told that before you can accept an answer you have to include it in the post so if those links go down you can still have an answer.

Comment: They are more than clear. I'm not writing a synopsis. Plus, the answer is the paragraph AFTER the links. Connect the dots... they are all there.